Cast to interface for implementation with pointer receiver
I want to check whether an received item of type any implements encoding.TextUnmarshaler, so I can invoke UnmarshalText on it. The problem is, it's method must be a pointer receiver, and this seems to be the source of quite some trouble.
import (
    "encoding"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

type MyStruct struct{ value string }

var _ encoding.TextMarshaler = (*MyStruct)(nil)

func (id MyStruct) MarshalText() (text []byte, err error) {
    return []byte(id.value), nil
}

var _ encoding.TextUnmarshaler = (*MyStruct)(nil)

func (id *MyStruct) UnmarshalText(data []byte) error {
    *id = MyStruct{value: string(data)}
    return nil
}

func TestIfICouldInvokeUnmarshalText(t *testing.T) {
    var ms any = MyStruct{value: "hello"}
    _, ok := (ms).(encoding.TextMarshaler)
    assert.True(t, ok)
    _, ok = (ms).(encoding.TextUnmarshaler)
    //assert.True(t, ok) // this is the first attempt, which will fail
    v := reflect.ValueOf(ms)
    if assert.True(t, v.Type().NumMethod() > 0 && v.CanInterface()) {
        if v.CanAddr() {
            _, ok := v.Addr().Interface().(encoding.TextUnmarshaler)
            assert.True(t, ok)
        } else {
            t.FailNow() // this is where I end up
        }
    }
}

Is there any (idiomatic) way to achieve that?

You probably want to check that the value passed A) implements some method and B) is a pointer. A) is done as you do by the type assertion and B) is done simply by that: Check via reflection that it is a pointer. No need to check that it is a pointer and implements smth as this is checked by A already.

Firstly,
var _ encoding.TextUnmarshaler = (*MyStruct)(nil)

guarantees that *MyStruct implements encoding.TextUnmarshaler, so why would you test for that?
Second, MyStruct does not implement encoding.TextUnmarshaler, and in extension:
var ms any = MyStruct{value: "hello"}

doesn't, so everything is correct there.
The reason that MyStruct doesn't implement encoding.TextUnmarshaler is that any method of it can not modify the original structure, since it's working on a copy, so any changes would be lost.
You've already got a copy in your interface, so the link to the original structure is lost anyway (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyValue struct{ Value string }

func (m MyValue) SetValue(value string) {
    m.Value = value
}

func main() {
    m := MyValue{"hello"}
    a := any(m)

    m.SetValue("world")
    a.(MyValue).SetValue("goodbye")
    fmt.Println(m, a)

    m.Value = "world"
    fmt.Println(m, a)
}

prints
{hello} {hello}
{world} {hello}

you have different values already. As a side note: a.(MyValue).Value = ... does not compile, since a.(MyValue).Value is not addressable.
*MyStruct does implement encoding.TextUnmarshaler, so try
var ms any = &MyStruct{value: "hello"}


Edit:
If you would try any trickery, you are in for a surprise (Go Playground):
package main

import (
    "encoding"
    "reflect"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type MyStruct struct{ value string }

var _ encoding.TextMarshaler = (*MyStruct)(nil)

func (id MyStruct) MarshalText() (text []byte, err error) {
    return []byte(id.value), nil
}

var _ encoding.TextUnmarshaler = (*MyStruct)(nil)

func (id *MyStruct) UnmarshalText(data []byte) error {
    *id = MyStruct{value: string(data)}

    return nil
}

func TestIfICouldInvokeUnmarshalText(t *testing.T) {
    var ms any = MyStruct{value: "hello"}
    _, ok := (ms).(encoding.TextMarshaler)
    if !ok {
        t.FailNow()
    }
    _, ok = (ms).(encoding.TextUnmarshaler)
    assert.False(t, ok)

    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(ms)))
    v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(ms)) // makes an addressable copy
    sp := v.Addr().Interface()

    u, ok := (sp).(encoding.TextUnmarshaler)
    if !ok {
        t.FailNow()
    }

    _ = u.UnmarshalText([]byte("world"))

    m, _ := ms.(MyStruct)
    assert.Equal(t, "world", m.value)
}

Yes, you could call UnmarshalText on a copy of your structure, but the results are lost and your original variable still has “hello” instead of “world”.

You want to test if a value implements encoding.TextUnmarshaler and that it's a pointer. You can write:
func IsUnmarshalerPointer(ms any) bool {
    _, ok := ms.(encoding.TextUnmarshaler)
    return ok && reflect.ValueOf(ms).Kind() == reflect.Pointer
}


I think what you want to do is something like this:
var ms any = MyStruct{value: "hello"}
_, ok := (ms).(encoding.TextMarshaler)
if !ok {
    t.FailNow()
}
_, ok = (ms).(encoding.TextUnmarshaler)
//assert.True(t, ok) // this is the first attempt, which will fail
v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(ms)))
v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(ms))
sp := v.Addr().Interface()
_, ok = (sp).(encoding.TextUnmarshaler)
if !ok {
    t.FailNow()
}


This does not do what you think it does. You are not invoking TextUnmarshaler on “it”, but on a copy (Go Playgound).
